# libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running into this error:
libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image

Per answers I've already seen, I've tried upgrading my version of libpng. However it appears that there are multiple versions installed on my system.

```
libpng12-0 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1    
libpng16-16 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2
```

If I run this command:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libpng
```

I see this:

```
libpng16.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

In trying to update libpng, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install libpng16-16
```

I'm assuming that the 1.2.54 version is my culprit but I'm not sure why it's even there or if I should remove it.

UPDATE

So I ran the following command trying to figure out what packages might be dependent on the 1.2.54 version and this is what I got:

```
libpng12-0
Reverse Depends:
usrmerge
libplymouth2
liblemonldap-ng-portal-perl
```

To get the above results I used this command:

```
apt-cache rdepends libpng12-0
```

UPDATE #2

Really watching my apache error logs it seems this error happens specifically after apache restart and usually this error also appears:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```